# how to remove duplicate arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove duplicate arrays? it's different from **array unique** because that is removing duplicate values inside array..

i get an array list like this

```
1. array('item' => 6, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 120)
2. array('item' => 6, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 120)
3. array('item' => 6, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 120)
4. array('item' => 22, 'quantity' => 8, 'price' => 30)
5. array('item' => 22, 'quantity' => 8, 'price' => 30)
```

how do i make like this while keeping the values?

```
3. array('item' => 6, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 120)
4. array('item' => 22, 'quantity' => 8, 'price' => 30)
```

---

code

```
$get = file_get_contents('URL');    
$json = json_decode($get, true);    
$results = print_r($json);    
file_put_contents('file.json', print_r($json, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What did you attempts come up with? Where are you stuck?

Comment: that's why im asking, I don't have any idea how to do it or what attempts to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

So as a example:

```
<?php

    $array = array(
                array('item' => 6, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 120),
                array('item' => 6, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 120),
                array('item' => 6, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 120),
                array('item' => 22, 'quantity' => 8, 'price' => 30),
                array('item' => 22, 'quantity' => 8, 'price' => 30)
            );

    $unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($unique);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => 6
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 120
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item] => 22
            [quantity] => 8
            [price] => 30
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this way:

```
if(serialize($a1) == serialize($a2))
```

You can serializ the arrays and then compare.